# Выполнить редирект при наличии ссылки

Tags: javascript

На странице вывода статей может появляться следующий код, с классом redirectText. Как автоматически на php выполнить редирект на ссылку, если она присутствует на странице с  с классом redirectText?

```
<ul class="redirectText">
  <li>
    <a href="/link/">Анкор</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var link = document.querySelector('.redirectText a');
if (typeof link.href !== 'undefinded') {
  console.log(link.href);
  // Раскомментировать при использовании
  //window.location.href = link.href;
}
```

```html
<ul class="redirectText">
  <li>
    <a href="https://ya.ru">Анкор</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="wrongClass">
  <li>
    <a href="https://ya.ru">Анкор</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это будет действовать для всех ссылок получается. Нужно только для тех, где есть в <ul> класс redirectText

Comment: Добавил уточнение. Но оно будет работать для первой найденной по этим признакам ссылки. Для перебора всех таких элементов, нужно `querySelector` заменить на `querySelectorAll` и перебрать и проверить все элементы в полученной коллекции.

Comment: Не работает почему то у меня на странице. http://jsfiddle.net/gdpv6k7j/

Comment: console.log что-то пишет?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gdpv6k7j/

Comment: скрипт отрабатывает еще до отрисовки элементов. Соответственно, никаких ссылок не находит. Нужно его переместить вниз. После html- разметки. В большинстве случаев всегда так рекомендуется делать.

Comment: Понял, теперь работает. Но хотелось бы конечно без задержки редирект, на PHP :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87633/discussion-between-eustatos-and-stop-tussin).